# How do I know what is the sys error in pthread_mutex_destroy?

Tags: c++, pthreads, system-calls

I'm using the command 'pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);'.

When I check the return value - it returns the number 16.
In the man page of this command it is said that a non-zero value is returned on failure, but there is no specified way to check it.

How can I know what is the source of my error if I have no access to errno messages?

Comment: the return value is defined well in the manual. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html

Answer (score 1):

Commandline: `perror 16`

Source: `perror("pthread_mutex_destroy");`

Or use `strerror(16);`